# GNU Assember 'SIREG' error

Tags: gnu-assembler

I am starting to learn Asm by looking at examples and online documentation. At the moment I am having trouble with an example I got off the internet.

```
hat.c
.
include hat.h
.
.
hat_create(hat_desc_t* hat)
{
.
.
copy_page((void*) hat->va_pd, (void*) page);  
.
return (page);
}
.
```

..........................................

```
hat.h
.
NPTE equ 1024
.
inline static void
copy_page(void* src, void* dest)
{
asm volatile
(
    "cld\n\t"
    "rep\n\t"
    "movsl"
    :
    : "D" (dest), "S" (src), "c" (NPTE)
    : "di", "si" <- This where the problem is.....
);
 }
```

gcc --version

`gcc (GCC) 4.6.1 20110627`

`gcc -fno-builtin -nostdinc -O2  -fomit-frame-pointer -c hat.c -o hat.o`

error: can’t find a register in class ‘SIREG’ while reloading ‘asm’
error: ‘asm’ operand has impossible constraints

Does anyone know how to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Simple change

:"di", "si"

to

:"0", "1"

This will fix the Problem.